# Is there a way to change the iOS low battery warning to pop up at 25%?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4 running 7.1.2., I tried using the cydia tweak lowpowerbanner but I don't think it worked. So if you could suggest another tweak that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a tweak named "Power Informer" is what you are looking for. 
Step by step instructions by WonderHowTo on [this](http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/take-full-control-over-low-battery-alerts-your-iphone-0159040/) link.